# How does Difficulty scale damage in Torchlight 2

Tags: torchlight-2

I made an an engineer with 2:1 VIT to STR, max bulwark and aegis shield, I find that at level 60 he is dying from 1 hit champions, boss attacks a little too often. Also regular mobs are hitting him pretty hard. He is a summoner with many of the +X% to minion damage. This is on Veteran difficulty. I would change to normal, but his minions clearing mobs so fast, they basically die within 1-3 seconds of appearing on the screen. He just walks from room to room basically. My problem is that I do not want to play where I can die from 1 hit, especially with that much defense, yet I cannot set any lower as the game is already easy enough in terms of killing.

I am thinking about making a new char altogether as I do not see this build as viable anymore for me. As for a new character, at which difficulty level would 1 hit kills not be an issue, yet the game still challenging enough? Perhaps better yet, does anyone know what changing the difficulty actually does in terms of scaling (ie: is a simple multiplication factor applied to all monsters damage?)

For the sake of the above example, defense stats: The char also has max healing bot for his level, which is 12).

[image]

Comment: Can you share some of your gear? In particular, 2:1 VIT to STR is great for tanking, assuming you have not invested much in other attributes, but if you have low resistances you WILL be 1 shot. Remember Torchlight 2 reduces damage by your resistances *for a flat amount*, **not** for a percentage. So resistances do not scale with damage and therefore they require some careful investment. The rate at which typical gear increases in resistances doesn't even come close to matching the sharp increase in damage as the game progresses - you have to use sockets and particular gear.

Comment: Also remember how valuable life on hit is. If you've played Diablo 3 you know that trying to tank with 0 healing abilities and no life gain on hit or damage is nigh impossible ... your healing bot will hardly compensate for the damage you will be suffering in combat - it can only counteract small losses in health and mana.

Comment: Voting to close, I don't see a real question here

Comment: Concur, please try rewording your question.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: agreed. Edited and changed title to make it more relevant/get to the heart of the issue in a way everyone would like to know.

Comment: The current balance in this game means damage scales up faster than armor does.  The most effective ways to avoid the one-shots are damage reduction (grell eyes and limoany skulls) and HP bonuses.

Comment: I am currently playing a engineer on Elite. You absolutly need the energy shield, when fully charged it will give you much more health than you would get from stacking vitality, also you can cast it again when the old one broke. You also need the Dynamo abilitiy from the same tree, for charging it up in more difficult situations.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you use pets for all your damage and are trying to build up your defensive capability. Have you tried shields? I know one-handed weapons tend not to have as much DPS, but you've said damage is a non-issue atm. 
Given that you have a high strength score, you would also have a pretty good block chance as well. When you successfully block with a shield, you take 0 damage from the attack (just like dodging.) Getting the right shield should boost your block chance by at least 10%, and give you physical armor passively to boot. This may or may not help you with your 1-hit problem, but if you have a 50% chance to block it should give you at least another half a hit before you go down.